# Grant user implicit permissions to folders of another user

Tags: debian, file-permissions, user-folders, user-groups

I've got the following file structure on Debian 8:

```
/folder                     userA:users 0750 rwxr-x--- (never edited)

# Dynamically created by userA with these permissions:
/folder/content1            userA:users 0700 rwx------
/folder/content1/file1.txt  userA:users 0644 rw-r--r--
/folder/content1/file2.txt  userA:users 0644 rw-r--r--
/folder/content2            userA:users 0700 rwx------
```

Now there is another `userB` which handles backups and must access all `contentX` folders and `fileX` inside them - but doesn't have permission to the `contentX` folders.

`userB` is also inside the `users` group.

Is there a way to grant `userB` access to the `contentX` folders, **without** modifying the permissions of the `contentX` folders - but perhaps of the top-level folder `folder`?

(Note that I'm **unable** to change how userA set's his permissions for it's folders/files)

Comment: If the directories are not readable/executable then what is in them is essentially unreachable. If there was a way to bypass this then these access flags would be completely worthless. So either userB is root, or userA changes the flags on the directories. Note that there are very legitimate purposes to have directories with 700, the ~/.ssh directory for instance must not be readable/writable by other users.

Comment: For sure there are legitimate purposes to have directories with 700 but shouldn't then the files also have these permissions or even more restrictive permissions set?

Comment: Why? Setting the perms on the directory means that you can add files to it without having to worry about their access.